# C code is not working in Linux compiler

Tags: c, linux, dev-c++

The code below is about **file operations in C**.

First program reads to file and store it to array after that program ask to user which question do you want from the file. If user enter, "2" program takes 2nd question from file (takes all characters between 2 and 3 numbers in file) and prints to the screen.

I wrote this code in DEV C++ compiler in Windows. It is working in Dev C++.

But **when I try this code in Linux terminal, the code asks the user an integer but it is not printing the result from file to the screen. It doesn't give any error and program closes**.

```
FILE* file = fopen("txt", "r"); 
char line[256];
char a[10][14];
char getIndex[2];
char firstIndex[2];
char secondIndex[2];
int firstIndexNum;
int secondIndexNum;

printf("Please enter number:");
fgets (getIndex, 100, stdin);
strcpy(firstIndex,getIndex);

firstIndexNum = atoi(firstIndex);

secondIndexNum = firstIndexNum + 1;

sprintf(secondIndex, "%d", secondIndexNum);


int i = 0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    strcpy(a[i],line);
    i++;
}
int sizeArray = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
for(int i=1;i<=sizeArray;i++){
    if(strstr(a[i-1], firstIndex) != NULL){
        while(strstr(a[i], secondIndex) == NULL){
            printf("%s",a[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

}  
fclose(file);
return 0;
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the program flow on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your file 'poems.txt' with CR/LF line endings to Unix line endings. This could be done with 'tr' command.

```
tr -d '\r' < input.file > output.file
```

Comment: @user9134929: It is remarkable that this was sufficient to 'solve' your problem.  However, the problems identified in comments by [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) mean that your code is at best incredibly fragile — for most purposes, it is still very broken unless you fix those issues too.

Comment: No problem, but do you understand why conversion solved your problem?

Comment: Also I agree absolutely with Jonathan comment, segmentation faults are lurking around almost every line in that source. It could be beneficial to all if @user9134929 add example of 'poems.txt' to question (first ten lines) and improve source code (add main() and stdio.h).

Comment: `dos2unix` is probably a little easier than running shell commands. The utility does not need two different files to operate (like `tr` does).